# Number to ascii in armv8 assembly

Tags: assembly, ascii, arm64, armv8

I need help converting numbers to ASCII. This is my code so far:

```
.global itoascii

itoascii:

    /* Initialize variables */
    mov x1, #10               /* Divisor */
    mov x2, buffer            /* Buffer address */

convert_loop:
    udiv x3, x0, x1           /* Divide the number by 10, quotient in x3, remainder in x0 */
    add x4, x0, #'0'          /* Convert remainder to ASCII */
    strb w4, [x2], #1         /* Store ASCII character in buffer and increment buffer pointer */

    cmp x3, #0                /* Check if quotient is zero */
    beq end_conversion        /* If quotient is zero, exit the loop */

    mov x0, x3                /* Update the number with the quotient */
    b convert_loop            /* Repeat the process */

end_conversion:
    mov x0, x2                /* Return the address of the buffer */
    ret

.data
    /* Put the converted string into buffer,
       and return the address of buffer */
    buffer: .fill 128, 1, 0
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Some general tips: (1) Format code blocks using `\`\`\`` on its own line at the beginning and end.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for more info on formatting.  (2) Use the [tag:assembly] tag for assembly language questions, as well as a tag for the specific architecture you are programming for; [tag:armv8] is okay but [tag:arm64] gets more attention.

Comment: That would store digits in reverse order.  Start from the end of the buffer and loop backwards.  Also, you need the remainder as the digit (with `msub` using the quotient, divisor, and original dividend.)  See [How do I print an integer in Assembly Level Programming without printf from the c library? (itoa, integer to decimal ASCII string)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46301894) for the algorithm in C which you could compile for AArch64.  Also, `mov` doesn't work to put a label address into a register in AArch64.

Comment: (3) In general, you should ask specific questions, rather than "I need to write this, please help."  Explain what you have tested, what went wrong (exact output and/or error messages), what you tried to fix it, etc.  People here will *help* you figure out your problem, but they won't just do it for you.